# How to draw point on map with R? Wind Rose onto Map

Tags: coordinate-system, r, mapping

I need transpose Wind Rose onto Map by image addition. I attempt to implement this code:

```
particolato <- read.csv('Acri_PM.csv')

Rose <- subset(particolato, wd != "") #remove blank records
Rose <- factor(Rose$wd) #save changes made by subset
Rose <- factor(Rose, levels = c("N","NNE", "NE", "ENE",
                                "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
                                "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW",
                                "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"))
WindRose1 <- ggplot(data.frame(Rose), aes(x=Rose, fill=Rose))+
  geom_bar(stat="count",width=1,colour="black",size=0.1, alpha= 0.5)+
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start=6.0729, direction = 1)+
  scale_color_discrete ()+
  ggtitle("Frequency Wind Rose", subtitle= "2014 - 2020, Acri (CS)") + 
  xlab("Wind Direction Recorded Every Day")+
  ylab("")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Direction")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face= "bold", color = "red"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size= 7), axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) 

WindRose1 


WindRose2 <- ggplot(data.frame(Rose), aes(x=Rose, fill=Rose))+
  geom_bar(stat="count",width=1,colour="black",size=0.1, alpha= 0.5)+
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start=6.075, direction = 1)+
  scale_color_discrete ()+ ggtitle("Frequency Wind Rose")+
  xlab("Wind Direction Recorded Every Day")+
  ylab("")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Direction")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face= "bold",
                                  color = "burlywood1",
                                  vjust = -3, hjust = -0.15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size= 8, color = "cornsilk1",
                                    hjust = 1.05, vjust = 1.4),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "cornsilk2", size= 12, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "none")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = NA),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill= "transparent", colour= NA),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill= "transparent", colour = NA))

WindRose2
ggsave(WindRose2, file="WindRose2.png", bg= "transparent", device = NULL)

Acri <- get_map(location= c(lon= 16.3868, lat= 39.48963), zoom = 17, maptype = "hybrid")
Map_Acri <- ggmap(Acri, extent = "device")
Map_Acri
ggsave(Map_Acri, file= "Map_Acri.png", device = NULL)

WindRose2_png <- readImage("~/R Language/WindRose2.png")
Map_Acri_png <- readImage("~/R Language/Map_Acri.png")
```

[image]
[image]

Practically it is necessary to superimpose one graph on another. They have same shapes, because saved 5.86 x 4.02 in image.

```
> dim(WindRose2_png)
[1] 1206 1759    4
> dim(Map_Acri_png)
[1] 1206 1759    3
```

WindRose2_png has four layers and Map_Acri_png only has three.

```
WindRose2_png <- readImage("~/R Language/WindRose2.png")
Map_Acri_png <- readImage("~/Map_Acri.png")
WindRoseMap <- (WindRose2_png[,,1:3] + Map_Acri_png)

imageShow(WindRoseMap)
```

[image]

How to draw point (point of my analysis) on map with R?

`CC <- points(16.44529,39.495616,pch=16,col="red")` this code does not give any result.

Comment: Please don't delete your old questions, especially if they have helped you, which it looks like they have.

Comment: This might require three steps back to go this one step forward. When you save a PNG with `ggsave` it doesn't save any coordinate information, so the georeferencing is lost, and when you read it back with `readImage` you get an NxM matrix located at (0,N) x (0,M). Unless you need the graphics separately, might it not be easier to do the whole plot in one ggplot graphic, with the map and the wind rose? You might need to do some coordinate calculations but all this image manipulations isn't the best way to do things...

Comment: Another possibility is to stick with the summed images, and the re-assign the georeferencing information. For this you need to know the *exact* coordinates of at least two points on the map in whatever coordinate system the map is projected in, or the exact coordinates of the pixels at the top, bottom, and sides of the image, but this is complicated by the embedding of the plot into a graphic device which means there might be borders and padding (the grey bits, perhaps).

Comment: @Spacedman I appreciate your help with this problem. Next time, I won't delete the question. 
Yes, I would like to solve everything with `ggplot`, but so far I have not succeeded.